# Check If Any Directories In a List File Are a Subdirectory of a Specific Directory

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I think I already know the answer to this and the answer is to "do the work" (i.e. loop over the individual entries in the file), but I want to see if anyone has any Bash magic.

**Situation:**

Let's say I have a directory: `/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/Documents/Thesis/Drafts/images/`

And I have a file that contains a list of directories:

```
/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/Documents/ProjectProposal/ 
/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/Documents/ProjectDesign/ 
/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/Documents/Thesis/Drafts/ 
...
```

**Question:**

Is there a quick and easy way in Bash scripting (maybe even a one-liner?) to check if any of the directories in the list file is a subdirectory of the first directory without simply looping through the file? I.e. Check to see if any directories in a list file are a subdirectory of a certain directory?

**Edit for further clarification:** If I have `/foo/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/Documents/ProjectProposal/`, I want to know if there's a subdirectory in the list file (i.e. `/foo/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/`) that includes it. String matching is sufficient; no need to check if directory actually exists.

I have implemented something similar using `grep -q $FILEDIRECTORY $accessLog` but that was a simpler situation where I grep'd an individual directory against the list file entries. Now I want to go the opposite direction and basically "grep" individual entires in the list file against an individual directory.

If I have to do a loop, that's what I'll do, I'm just interested in learning if there is a "better way".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean you might have something like `/foo/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/Documents/ProjectProposal/`? Or do you mean you want to take only the last part of the path, the final directory name (e.g. `ProjectProposal/`) and then see if you have `./foo/ProjectProposal`? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: The former. If I have ```/foo/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/Documents/ProjectProposal/```, I want to know if there's a subdirectory in the list file (i.e. ```/foo/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/```) that includes it. String matching is sufficient; no need to check if directory actually exists.

Comment: (1) Please don't use 54-character long pathnames as examples unless you really *really **really*** need to.  (2) Please don't say "Edit for further clarification" and then, basically, repeat what you already said.  (3) Example input is like one shoe. Having one shoe is better than nothing, but it's a ***lot*** less useful than having two. Having example input is better than nothing, but it's a ***lot*** less useful than having example input *and the corresponding expected/desired output.* … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  In particular, you use the word ‘‘subdirectory’’, but then you write sentences that make it sound like you're looking for a superdirectory (ancestor directory), and I can't tell which one you really want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disadvantage with using `grep` is that either you need to allow regular expressions so that you can bind the pattern match to the beginning of the string or you need to disable regular expressions and hope that every pattern and target match have a common and non-repeated prefix.

The problem with regular expressions is that a pattern like `^/mnt/one.two/` will match a string `/mnt/one/two/`. The problem with fixed strings is that `/mnt/one/two/` might match `/one/two/`.

A different approach is to use `awk` to compare the target directory path with each line in turn, ensuring that the start of the target and the start of the pattern are aligned. Assuming you have your list of directories in `file`:

```
dir="/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/Documents/Thesis/Drafts/images/"
awk -v dir="$dir" '$0 == substr(dir, 1, length($0))' file
```

And the output for your example is

```
/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/Documents/Thesis/Drafts/
```

Comment: Or `awk 'index($0, dir) == 1'`

Comment: This was a really elegant answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When

```bsh
$ dir="/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/Documents/Thesis/Drafts/images/"
$ cat file
/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/Documents/ProjectProposal/
/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/Documents/ProjectDesign/
/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/Documents/Thesis/Drafts/
...
```

then, if you only care that a match exists and you don't care which line in the file matches:

```
if echo "$dir" | grep -q -f file; then
  echo "a match exists in the file"
else
  echo "no match"
fi
```

Comment: What if `file` contains `/Drafts` only?

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`'s [`rindex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724503/):

```
dir=/mnt/Transfer/Downloads/Documents/Thesis/Drafts/images/
perl -lsne 'print if rindex($dir, $_, 0) == 0' -- -dir="$dir" < file
```